# Mapkit route of two locations in mapview not working indian latitude and longtude?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkpolyline

here is my code :

## Working :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.7833, -122.4167);//san fransisco
MKPlacemark *sourcePlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:sourceCoords addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *source = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlacemark];

// Make the destination location
CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.0500, -118.2500);//los angeles
MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoords addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];
```

## NotWorking :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.0441, +80.1831);
MKPlacemark *sourcePlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:sourceCoords addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *source = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlacemark];


 Make the destination location   CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.0545, +80.2114);
 MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoords addressDictionary:nil];
 MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];
```

polyline not showing in mapview .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple maps is not supporting Directions in india. you have to use Google Maps for Directions in india. [you can check map feature availability here](http://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions)

Comment: if we implement the direction in pakistan which is also not in the supporting list but send a build to client in US will direction work or not?